# Get value of attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get ID value:

```
for( var i=0; i<= 35; i++){
    var id = $('.image_carousel #' + i)
    var c = id.attr('id')
    console.log(c)
}
```

console.log give me 36 times "undefined". Why? what I do wrong here?

HTML

```
<% @post_images.each_with_index do |f,index| %>
        <div class='image_carousel' id='<%= index %>'><%= link_to 'abcde, '#',:class => "photo"  %></div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: If you do `console.log(id)` what does it show?

Comment: for example this [prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document, selector: ".image_carousel #25", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]

Comment: Try using `var c = id.prop('id');`

Comment: can you post your html

Comment: It should also show a `length` property (I think); is it `1`, `0`..?

Comment: The id would be the value of i, wouldn't it? If you're getting undefined, then you're not searching the DOM correctly.

Comment: Is it possible that the above code is being run before the elements have been created? This might be happening if the above code isn't wrapped in an on-document-ready function, such as jQuery's implementation: `$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for elements of various ids that are **descendants** of an element that is a member of `image_carousel`.

You should be looking for elements with those ids that are **also** members of that class.

Remove the descendant combinator (the space) from your selector.

```
var id = $('.image_carousel#' + i);
```

Note that since an id must be **unique** in the document, you can probably simply remove the class selector as well.

```
var id = $('#' + i);
```

Comment: I take *one* moment to blink...tsk.